# How to manually define input split for mapper function in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a text file which I want to parse through map reduce.
File has below mentioned format:

```
<main node>
<type 1> --data--
<type 2> ---data
.
.
.
<type n> --data
</main node>

<main node>
<type 1> --data--
<type 2> ---data
.
.
.
<type n> --data
</main node>
```

I would like the map function split according to main node..such that each split has exactly one main node and its data.
all the main node starts with same syntax.
Is it possible to define such input split for Map function? 
P.S. this is not xml file..although it looks like one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input file is in the XML Format.
In that case you can replace your TextInputFormat class to XMLInputFormat class.
That means instead of mapper getting each line as input, it gets each main_node as input.

Checkout the link below,

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/integration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/text/wikipedia/XmlInputFormat.java

Find a working example at 
https://github.com/ajaysadhu/XML_MR_Reader

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Although it looks like xml format but it is not exactly in xml. I would say it is very ill formatted xml. Hence, I have not been able to parse it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, you have to read your whole file as a single split by setting issplittable() to false.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is pluggable system. 
Hadoop does provide standard InputFormat like Text , binary etc.. But if you have custom format file then you need to write your own InputFormat and Implement custom RecorReader to generate input split. If you implement these then you can control where to split data and each Mapper ingest one input spit at a time